# What to do with cash money?

Tags: japan, money, security, new-zealand

This is a *first world's problem question*. The thing is I thought it was a good idea to carry cash. But I'm realizing that I'm not spending as much as I thought , so I have to be carry this money, and being super careful.

**What should I do to secure my money, and don't loose a crazy amount in the try?**

Comment: You can paypal it all to me.

Comment: @gerrit I would, but it's cash :P

Comment: https://www.attheregister.com/paypalcash

Comment: You could try spending it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/carrying-large-amounts-of-cash-in-japan

Comment: Overpay your credit card, then use it as you wish. Once done with the trip, refund the rest to your account, as I understood refunding excess credit card balance has no fees.

Comment: What currency is your cash? If you have JPY it's going to be hard to use it to pay your NZ credit card. Are you expecting to need the cash later in your trip (perhaps in a third currency) or do you just want to bring it home somehow?

Comment: There exist ATMs  that can be used to transfer cash to your bank account.

Comment: The currency is USD.

Comment: If you are staying at a hotel and you didn't prepay the rate, or if you charged dinner or drinks to the room, then this is a good opportunity to get rid of all your hard currency, less whatever you need to get to the airport. You can pay the remainder of your hotel bill by credit card as normal. I have never found a hotel who refused this, even if I was just disposing of change!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is depositing the funds (beyond what you'll need in the near future) in a bank account you already have, if you can find an ATM or something which supports that.  The rest of this answer is only relevant if that's not possible.

If possible, open an account with a reputable large international bank that has a presence in Japan, and deposit the funds there.  Even if you wind up finding a place where you have to withdraw the funds before moving on to the next country, you can breathe easier while you're in Japan.

Once you have the money electronically, see if you can get it to a credit card company (if you have one) and make it as a payment so you have a credit balance.  Then you might not have as much in interest fees on "cash advances" and/or card purchases.